# Webexception caught with youtube api on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

WebException was caught while using youtube api (https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{user}/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=10&v=2")
This is happening always and only with device (windows phone-8)
However no issue I could find when running through emulator (WVGA-512).

Currently using     `DownloadStringAsync(url);` of System.Net.WebClient

Pls find the exception below.

```
    System.Net.WebException was caught
  _HResult=-2146233079
  _message=An exception occurred during a WebClient request. 
  HResult=-2146233079
  IsTransient=false
  Message=An exception occurred during a WebClient request. 
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at AppStudio.Data.YouTubeDataProvider.<Load>d__a.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at AppStudio.Data.VideosDataSource.<LoadData>d__0.MoveNext()
  InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
       _HResult=-2147467261
       _message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       HResult=-2147467261
       IsTransient=false
       Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       Source=System.Net
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsState.SetResponse(WebResponse response)
            at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
       InnerException:
```

Tried with HttpClient too but with no success.
I'd appreciate if anyone can help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Could you try using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient instead? I would normally assume at this point the error's being thrown from a flaky Internet connection so make sure the Wi-Fi or data connection isn't being cut out as you're testing.